# php click to sort ordering

Tags: php, sorting

I've a table with columns that are sorted descending when the header is clicked once, however I'd like to invert the ordering when clicked again.

How do I update the variable $sort when the a tag is clicked each time, or is there a better way of trying to do this?

```
$orderBy = array('one','two','three');

$sort = "DESC";
$order = 'column1';

if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
$order = $_GET['orderBy'];
}

$query = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 ORDER BY $order $sort LIMIT 20";
```

HTML

```
<tr>
<th>
<a href="?orderBy=column1">1</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="?orderBy=column2">2</a>
</th>
<th>
<a href="?orderBy=column3">3</a>
</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Take a look at jQuery "ajax" ( http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ) or a JS table plugin like DataTables ( https://datatables.net/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

PHP way - it's ok, but reloads the data at every request.

```
<?php
// the very top of the page: start a session to remember the previous options
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["order"]))
  $_SESSION["order"] = array("col" => false, "dir" => false);
// set defaults
$dir = 0;
$col = "column1";
$orderBy = array("column1", "column2", "column3");
$orderDir = array("DESC", "ASC");
// check $_GET data
if (isset($_GET["orderBy"]) && in_array($_GET["orderBy"], $orderBy)) {
  $col = $_GET["orderBy"];
}
// check if same col is clicked as last time
// if it is the same => change the order, if not => use default
if ($_SESSION["order"]["col"] == $col) {
  // 1 becomes 0, 0 becomes 1
  $dir = 1 - $_SESSION["order"]["dir"];
}
// remember current options
$_SESSION["order"]["col"] = $col;
$_SESSION["order"]["dir"] = $dir;
// set the order
$sort = $orderDir[$dir];
// set the correct query
$query = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 ORDER BY $col $sort LIMIT 20";
```

The Javascript way:

- use the PHP to provide the data, but not to sort it (remove the links from the table head)
- print the HTML table
- load at the end of HTML a script that sorts the table data on the client side - there are a lot of plugins... example: [very simple plugin: sorttable.js](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js) (it's old but very simple and good)

Answer (score 0):

in_array()  Checks if a value exists in an array

use it :

```
$orderBy = array('column1','column2','column3');
```